# Why did my old Code Signing Certificate not popup the Windows SmartScreen but the new new does?

Tags: certificate, signing, smartscreen

Our normal code signing certificate for our apps expired a few days ago. This has worked for 3 years without any SmartScreen popups i.e. Windows Protected your PC.

So yesterday we received our new standard certificate. Now we get the SmartScreen popup.

I know that there are many postings about needing EV to avoid this but it is not making sense to me since our old standard certificate did not get the SmartScreen popup. WHY?

We have been signing our code with SignTool for many years. We have dozens of apps that have been installed and many customers (many a thousand) over the past 10 or more years.

So I just don't get it. Old Normal Cert did NOT get a popup. New one does get a popup.

Answer (score 0):

Each standard code signing certificate has its own reputation. Apparently your old certificate had enough reputation to hide SmartScreen popup. Your new certificate needs some time and downloads.

Side note: EV code signing certificates (not the cheap standard code signing certificates) have a unique identifier which makes it easier to maintain reputation across certificate renewals.